# In Windows, how do I run a shortcut into the background from a command prompt?

Tags: windows, dos

```
cmd /C "myshortcut1.lnk"
cmd /C "myshortcut2.lnk"
```

Works, but gives me a pop-up DOS window which, when closed, kills my two loaded programs.  Same is true for this:

```
start /B cmd /C "1.lnk"
start /B cmd /C "2.lnk"
start /B cmd /C "3.lnk"
start /B cmd /C "4.lnk"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `start`:

```
start myshortcut1.lnk
start myshortcut2.lnk
```

I do not have a Windows machine nearby to test right now, but should work.

Comment: Sorry, I used the wrong command name (confused it with xdg-open). Please try again.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
C:\> my_shortcut.lnk
```

Comment: I tried this:

   start /B cmd /C "1.lnk"
   start /B cmd /C "2.lnk"
   start /B cmd /C "3.lnk"
   start /B cmd /C "4.lnk"

but this results in a command prompt window that, when closed, kills my 4 other windows.

Comment: For me both "my_shortcut.lnk" and "cmd /c my_shortcut.lnk" works without killing the programs when the prompt window is closed. We need more info. What Windows version are you using? Have you tried what I suggested with a well known link (like the Notepad one in the Start Menu)?

Comment: This has always worked for me too - just tried it again to be sure. We're not getting the full picture here.